# The property doesn't update on the UI consistently

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have the problem that one property of the selected item in collection view doesn't update consistently. I have INotifyPropertyChanged and all of that. The property that I am talking about is progress in CurrentEntry. As you can see after that I have Console.WriteLine with success string so I know for a fact that everything went as It should and I don't get any exceptions. I even check website that it updated there just to be sure. As I said it is very consistent, sometimes I can do the task 5 times successfully so that it updates and other 5 times it doesn't update.

I'm not sure what could be causing this. I tried putting the line where I update it in MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread but this probably isn't relevant as I am updating property not a label or anything. This is MVVM not code behind.

```
async Task Info()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            try
            {
                if (currentEntry.progress < currentEntry.media.Episodes)
                {
                    string token = Preferences.Get("token", "default_value");
                    var anilistGraphQlHttpClient =
                        new GraphQLHttpClient("https://graphql.anilist.co", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

                    anilistGraphQlHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                    var IncreaseProgressEntry = new GraphQLRequest
                    {
                        Query = @"mutation IncreaseProgress($id: Int, $progress: Int) {   SaveMediaListEntry(id: $id, progress: $progress) {     id     progress     status   } } ",
                        OperationName = "IncreaseProgress",
                        Variables = new
                        {
                            id = CurrentEntry.id,
                            progress = currentEntry.progress + 1
                        }
                    };
                    var graphQlResponseAnimeList =
                        await anilistGraphQlHttpClient.SendQueryAsync<Data>(IncreaseProgressEntry);

                    CurrentEntry.progress = currentEntry.progress + 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("success");
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(httpRequestException);
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<Toast>().Show("No internet");
                });

            }
            catch (GraphQLHttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Preferences.Set("token", "default_value");
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//LandingPage");

                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<Toast>().Show("Token revoked or expired");
                });

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    DependencyService.Get<Toast>().Show("Unexpected error happened");
                });
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

CurrentEntry type model

```
public class ListEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public int? id { get; set; }
    public Media media { get; set; }
    public int? _score;

    public int? score
    {
        get => _score;
        set
        {
            if (value == _score)
                return;

            _score = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int _Progress;
    public int progress
    {
        get => _Progress;
        set
        {
            if (value == _Progress)
                return;

            _Progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

My xaml:

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="OtakuApp.Pages.AnimeListPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
x:Name="AnimeListPagee">
<RefreshView
    x:Name="HomeRefreshView"
    BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue"
    Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
    RefreshColor="White">
    <CollectionView
        x:Name="CollectionView1"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        IsGrouped="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding AnimeGroupObservable}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentEntry}"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="15" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label
                        Margin="30,15,0,5"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="25">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Span Text=": " />
                                <Span Text="{Binding entryCount}" />
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame
                        Margin="15,0,15,0"
                        Padding="0"
                        BackgroundColor="Brown"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        HeightRequest="150"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <Grid
                            Padding="0"
                            xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            ColumnSpacing="0"
                            RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Aspect="AspectFill"
                                Source="{Binding media.CoverImage.Large}" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="5"
                                FontSize="14"
                                LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                MaxLines="3"
                                Text="{Binding media.Title.UserPreferred}"
                                TextColor="White" />
                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="5"
                                FontSize="14"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                TextColor="White"
                                VerticalOptions="End">
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="Score: " />
                                        <Span Text="{Binding score}" />
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                            <StackLayout
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding progress}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                                <BoxView
                                    Margin="15,0,15,0"
                                    HeightRequest="2"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Color="White" />
                                <Label
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding media.Episodes}"
                                    TextColor="White" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Frame
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Padding="0"
                                xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding BindingContext.InfoCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"
                                xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                                xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimationColor="White"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                CornerRadius="30"
                                HeightRequest="45"
                                VerticalOptions="Start">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="30"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Text="+"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            </Frame>
                            <Frame
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Padding="0"
                                xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding BindingContext.InfoCommand2, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"
                                xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                                xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimationColor="White"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                CornerRadius="30"
                                HeightRequest="45"
                                VerticalOptions="End">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="30"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    Text="-"
                                    TextColor="White"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</RefreshView>
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the code for the `progress` property

Comment: Done, I've pasted the whole model that CurrentEntry uses

Comment: that appears correct, although your use of "currentEntry" and "CurrentEntry" is very confusing.  Is "CurrentEntry" the object the UI is bound to?  Putting the "WriteLine" statement in the property setter might be a better check than where you currently have it

Comment: I have observablecollection of type ListEntry. CurrentEntry is of the same type. I bind selecteditem in collectionview to CurrentEntry to make changes to selectedItem this way. I've tried putting WriteLine to setter to print _Progress. After _Progress = value; This is an example result: When UI doesn't update for example from value 1 to 2. It will print 2 in console. And when I try to do task again it will print 2 instead of 3. And will go 2 on UI.

Comment: I didn't have this problem when I had ONLY CurrentEntry.progress++ in the task. But I have Task.Run to utilize more threads and try, catch for obvious reasons

Comment: Could you please post the `yourpage.xaml` file ? In addition, you can debug if the the value of `CurrentEntry.progress` has updated each time.

Comment: I've posted xaml. Search for xct:TouchEffect.Command if you want to find the command. It's part of community toolkit. The result of debugging seems to be the same as I did for the setter, so please check the above comments. Thank you

Comment: Something weird is happening. When doing that task of increasing and decreasing this property my whole collection view does refresh command? Is that normal? It's extremely weird. I am sure that I don't have Refresh in increase and decrease command. I've put WriteLine in refresh in finally block and it happens when I do the other commands.

Comment: Any thoughts?  I am clueless, And what my refresh command does is that it pulls new new list from API and replaces the current one. I've noticed it from page scrolling to the top

Comment: So the whole problem was that I had IsRefreshing binded to IsBusy Property which I had in all commands. I didn't know it triggers command. I thought it only does the visualization. Can I still have visualization while using all the commands but triggering refresh command only when pulling to refresh?

Comment: Maybe you haven't  posted the right code. What's the code of  `CurrentEntry ` and the viewmodel of page `AnimeListPage`?  If it is convienient for you,could you please post a basic demo so that we can help you better?

Comment: As I said the whole problem was setting IsRefreshing to true which also triggers refresh command which is not what I intended and what caused the problems. I've read in the docs that setting IsRefreshing to true on collection view not only shows the visualization but also triggers the command. I have only one command that should do it, but I had it on all of my commands. Seems to be a bad design when I asked someone about this.

Comment: Honestly I didn't expect that it triggers the command, I thought it only does the visualization

Comment: Where is command `RefreshCommand`  and `IsRefreshing ` used in your viewmodel?  Above, you said that the variable `CurrentEntry` does not update properly,  now you're saying it's about the variable `IsRefreshing`.    Since we couldn't see the other code ,so it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: I don't think you understand what's going on.. IsBusy = IsRefreshing right? right.. Now because of that when I've had IsBusy in my changing property task it would ALSO fire refresh command BECAUSE IsRefreshing NOT ONLY triggers visualization BUT ALSO the command. Therefore it would do two commands messing up updating the property, and another problem bringing me to the top of the page which shouldn't happen. And what my refresh command does it pulls complete new list from API and REPLACES the current one. That's why these problems happened

Comment: By the way I've told you I've solved the problem, this is the problem

Comment: Straight from the docs - "Manually setting the IsRefreshing property to true will trigger the refresh visualization, and will execute the ICommand defined by the Command property."

Comment: Also, important fact that because of IsBusy at the beginning of my updating property task it would mean that refresh command happens always before the updating.